# Block instagram from router

Tags: networking, router, lan

I have a TP-LINK Archer C50 router.
From the "access control" menu, in the left panel, I have created a rule to lock the access to any urls containing the key word "intagram".

No way, I have still access to Instagram, I cannot stop the access to this website.

How can I block the access to instagram from my LAN ? It seems this url no to be true one or something else...

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For people who would have the same problem, the solution was to block all the ports from 1 to 65535 for the keyword "instagram".

You can do this by creating a "host" for a range of IP address or a single static IP addresses of the device concerned by the restriction. The creation of a host can be done under "access control" menu.